# how to create a custom infoWindow for osmdroid Polyline

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid, infowindow, polyline

I'm trying to create a custom infoWindow for a polyline that contains just text and that has to be shown at the center of the polyline "segment". I have created a simple InfoWindow class (**MyInfoWindow**):

```
class MyInfoWindow(layoutResId : Int, map : MapView): InfoWindow(layoutResId, map) {
    init{
        if(titleId == RES_ID){
            setResId(map.context)
        }
        mView.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener{
            override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                if(p1!!.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    close()
                }
                return true
            }

        })
    }
    override fun onOpen(item: Any?) {
        val overlay : OverlayWithIW = item as OverlayWithIW
        val title : String = overlay.getTitle()
        if(mView == null){
            return
        }
        val temp : TextView = mView.findViewById(titleId)
        temp.text = title
    }

    override fun onClose() {

    }

    companion object{
        private const val RES_ID : Int = 0
        var titleId : Int = RES_ID
        fun setResId(context : Context){
            titleId = context.resources.getIdentifier("id/poly_title", null, context.packageName)
            Log.i("title", "$titleId")
        }
    }
}
```

and an xml file that contains only the textView to show(**polyline_layout.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poly_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxEms="17"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

From the designed class that handles the Polyline I've done this

```
_polyline = Polyline(_map)
_polyline!!.setTitle("distance test")
_infoWindow = MyInfoWindow(R.layout.polyline_layout, _map)
_polyline!!.setInfoWindow(_infoWindow)
```

What can I do to show the text in the middle of the polyline's segments.

Unforunately with this code I can only see the segmente without the text even when I've clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your own bubble, you MUST use specific ids.
(and doing that, also remove your code related to retrieval of your own id)

See:
https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2#9-creating-your-own-bubble-layout